# JMeter once only global variable initializing

Tags: multithreading, properties, jmeter

I cannot find a way of initializing an int variable as property (global) only once when my test starts. My test plan has multiple threads, multiple loop iterations and I'd like to use a variable inside my beanshell script but before anything, I want it to have a certain value, and afterwards let the loops and threads define it as needed.
I tried through UDV configuration but with no luck. Also, I would like to have it global (as property, for multiple thread groups) but couldn't find a way for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason for not using the property instead? For instance you can add the next line to *user.properties* file

```
foo=100
```

or pass it to JMeter via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jfoo=100 -n -t yourscript.jmx
```

Once done you can use the value in 3 ways:

1. Using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function where required:

   ```
   ${__P(foo,)}
   ```
2. Convert it into a global variable using [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configuration element

   [image: User Defined Variables - property to variable]
3. When it comes to Beanshell - use `props` shorthand instead of `vars`

   ```
   int foo = Integer.parseInt(props.get("foo"));
   ```

JMeter Properties are global for the whole JVM to they can be accessed from multiple Thread Groups. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

Comment: Assuming I add it to property file, it would be possible to change it's value through the test (After initialization in the property)?

Comment: Of course, you can do it via Beanshell or [__setProperty()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) function.